# jqGrid: how to hide a specific search field in the search toolbar

Tags: javascript, css, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid with a search toolbar. Now for several columns I do not need the search field, because I do not want to make them searchable (i.e. a column of checkboxes). For these columns I want to hide the search field in the search toolbar. 
I have read in the jqGrid [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options) that the `viewable` option can be set to `false`. 
Here is the part where I set the `viewable` option:

```
colModel :[ 
          {name:'checkbox', index:'checkbox', width:'3%', viewable:false},
```

Here is how I create the search toolbar:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#listTable").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false});
});
```

According to the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options), the `viewable` option is valid only if the `viewGridRow` method is activated.

But when I use (activate) the `viewGridRow` method, that creates another dialog. In that dialog the column whose `viewable` is set to false does not appear. But I want to hide the search field in the search toolbar not in a new dialog. How can I do that?

I have also tried to get the corresponding `div` (the one that surrounds my search field) and set its `style.display` to `none`. But that does not help.

Is there a way I could hide this search field in the search toolbar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jqGrid: Search Toolbar disable for some columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114613/jqgrid-search-toolbar-disable-for-some-columns)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your column model add the option `search:false` for the column where you do not want the search filter.
Ex:

```
{
    label : 'User',
    name : 'name',
    width : 500,
    sortable : false,
    search : false
}
```

You can find the documentation [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config#colmodel_).

Comment: Life Saver, thank you so much. There are so many documentations one can't figure out which is the official one and they all suck.