# How to disable jqGrid's Search Toolbar for some columns?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have added the search toolbar to my jqGrid and was wondering is there anyway to search certain columns instead of all of them?

By default, the search toolbar shows a search field for every column.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you define `search:false` property for the column in the [colModel](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options) the search toolbar will have no input element for the column.

Comment: @Oleg this work with last version?. I use `jqGrid('filterToolbar',{searchOperators : true});` and `search:false` in each field I don't show the input and doesn't work

Comment: Shit, I'm using false like a string. Sorry

Comment: @Biruwon: It's no problem. By the way you can use `cmTemplate: {search: false}` to set default value for `search` property. See [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935) for more details.